# Почему this в data возвращает undefined?

Tags: vue.js

```
    let app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
            return { 
                isActive: true,
                active: this.isActive,
            }
        },
    
        
    }).mount('#app');

    console.log(app.$data.active); // undefined
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что на момент создания `data` компонента (а `this` в `Options API` указывает именно на компонент (когда возможно)) еще не существует.

Непонятно, чего вы пытаетесь добиться таким кодом, зачем вам 2 свойства, означающих, по сути, одно и то же. Если это умышленно, вынесите `active` в `computed`.